# Redirections with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to have a Home Page and with differents links redirect to the differents pages of my app.

I used `<Routes>` and `<Route>` to redirect them but is not working. It stay in blank.

I want to `Navebar` be the `layout` here, so I read that it must contain the other `Routes` inside of it

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router';
import './App.scss';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Home from './components/Home/index'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Navbar/>}>
                <Route exact={true} index element={<Home/>}></Route>
                <Route exact={true} path='contact' element={<Contact/>}></Route>
            </Route>      
        </Routes>

        </>

    );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter> 
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is the Navbar (which is the onlyone is showing)

```
class Navbar extends Component{
    state = { clicked: false}

    handleClick = () =>{
        this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <nav className='navbar-items'>
                    <img alt='mRadio' className='navbar-logo' href="../Home/index" src={require('../../assets/images/mRadio.png')}></img>
                    <div className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                        {MenuItems.map((item, index)=>{
                            return (
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                                </li>
                            )                            
                        })
                        }                   
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </>
        )  
    } 
}
```

And this is the Home page:

```
const Index = () => {
    return (
        <div className='main'>
            <video src={videomRadio} autoPlay loop muted/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And this is a Third page:

```
const Index = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>CONTACT PAGE</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you import the BrowserRouter on the index.js or where your App component is render ?

Comment: Yes, I will show you

Comment: What version of react.js are you using? You can check it in your `package.json` file

Comment: It says `"version": "0.1.0"`

Comment: Sry i have done some syntax error so I updated my answer.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re using the latest version 6, don't use Switch, now is become Routes, try to change the path like this for example if is nested component:

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'; //just in case

//...

const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Navbar/>}>
              <Route index element={<Home/>} />
              <Route path='contact' element={<Contact/>}/>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
       </>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

create a child in home and third page.that gives access to that page directly.

Comment: Answers are expected to be specific. See [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).